# Rename files do the tree folder name in terminal, shell mac or shell linux

Tags: linux, macos, shell, rename, osx-yosemite

I'm working with a tree of folders and files with the structure

- \ Stories \ 00 \ 0 \ 00000 \ temp.xxx
- \ Stories \ 00 \ 0 \ 00001 \ temp.xxx
- ...
- \ History \ 10 \ 5 \ 10552 \ temp.xxx
- \ History \ 10 \ 5 \ 10553 \ temp.xxx
- ...
- \ History \ 45 \ 9 \ 45998 \ temp.xxx
- \ History \ 45 \ 9 \ 45999 \ temp.xxx

What I need is to rename the files so that temp.xxx is changed into a sequenced file name as shown below:

- \ Stories \ 00 \ 0 \ 00000 \ 00000.xxx
- \ Stories \ 00 \ 0 \ 00001 \ 00001.xxx
- ...
- \ History \ 10 \ 5 \ 10552 \ 10552.xxx
- \ History \ 10 \ 5 \ 10553 \ 10553.xxx
- ...
- \ History \ 45 \ 9 \ 45998 \ 45998.xxx
- \ History \ 45 \ 9 \ 45999 \ 45999.xxx

Comment: See if this link is helpful. http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-easy-ways-to-batch-rename-files-on-the-mac--mac-46999

Comment: thanks prasanna, but what im looking for is a command line in shell that can do it whitout GUI interactions

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is uniform and you have the depth of 3 inside your History folder, perhaps the intuitive way would be having nested for loops and then use the mv to rename.

The following code assumes that you have one file in each folder in layer3 and your /History does not contain anything other than directories.

```
for layer1 in /History/*; do
    for layer2 in /History/$layer1/*; do
        for layer3 in /History/$layer1/$layer2/*; do
           for files in /History/$layer1/$layer2/$layer3/*; do
                mv files $layer3.xxx
            done
        done
    done
done
```

perhaps these two links are also helpful:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539583/how-do-i-recursively-list-all-directories-at-a-location-breadth-first

Comment: You may want to quote your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a command like this:

```
find . -name "temp*" | sed -E 's|(.*)\/(.*)\/temp(.[a-z]{3})|mv & \1\/\2\/\2\3|g' | source /dev/stdin
```

**Step by step explanation.**

This is your sample input:

```
$ find . -name "temp*"
./History/10/5/10552/temp.xxx
./History/10/5/10553/temp.xxx
./Stories/00/0/00000/temp.xxx
./Stories/00/0/00001/temp.xxx
```

I tweak the output to suit the required output.

```
$ find . -name "temp*" | sed -E 's|(.*)\/(.*)\/temp(.[a-z]{3})|\1\/\2\/\2\3|g'
./History/10/5/10552/10552.xxx
./History/10/5/10553/10553.xxx
./Stories/00/0/00000/00000.xxx
./Stories/00/0/00001/00001.xxx
```

So, we transform every `temp*` into a `mv` command with required output names. The command looks like this:

```
$ find . -name "temp*" | sed -E 's|(.*)\/(.*)\/temp(.[a-z]{3})|mv & \1\/\2\/\2\3|g'
mv ./History/10/5/10552/temp.xxx ./History/10/5/10552/10552.xxx
mv ./History/10/5/10553/temp.xxx ./History/10/5/10553/10553.xxx
mv ./Stories/00/0/00000/temp.xxx ./Stories/00/0/00000/00000.xxx
mv ./Stories/00/0/00001/temp.xxx ./Stories/00/0/00001/00001.xxx
```

To execute every command from the previous output, we must add `| source /dev/stdin` at the end of the command.

The results will be the following:

```
$ find . -name "*.xxx"
./History/10/5/10552/10552.xxx
./History/10/5/10553/10553.xxx
./Stories/00/0/00000/00000.xxx
./Stories/00/0/00001/00001.xxx
```